# How to get string from NSArray which contains bracket

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

my code is like this:
(here name is NSArray and object is also array which is passed as function parameter)

```
[name addObject:object];
NSlog(@"%@",name);
```

When i do this then i got output like this:

```
{name:\"Malay Basu"\ date:\"2013-04-18"\ senderId:\"24" receiverId:\"25"}
```

Now when i am retrieving name field of array into string then i got the string as:

```
NSString *temp = [name valueForKey:@"name"];
output: `( Malay Basu )`
```

Now when i do string operations like string appending or comparison of string then i got the error like:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16635ed0'
```

To remove this error i need this string without bracket as displays above. So i need `Malay Basu` instead of `( Malay Basu )`.So what is my next step to fetch proper string into another string variable because i need to do operations like string compare,string appending. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you used an `nsarray` thinking it as `nsstring`

Comment: try `nslog(@"%@",[[name valueForKey:@"name"] className]);`

Comment: For getting only `Malay Basu` Give a try to  `NSLog(@"Your name is : %@", [temp objectAtIndex:0]);`

Comment: where is your question, and what about this question? solved>

Comment: Yes this problem is solved but my another problem is of i can not kept as login in UIWebView(in Google+) although one time i logged in in my app.Can you please look at there.Thanks.My questions are on above links.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's very hard to determine what you're doing.  Could you include some actual code and actual console output from  NSLog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the purpose of the methods you are using.

`-valueForKey:` when called on an `NSArray`

Returns an array containing the results of invoking `valueForKey:` using key on each of the array's objects.

So your object isn't a string, it's an array of strings.
The log statement shows brackets because that is the log notation for `NSArray`. Similarly {} brackets are the log notation for `NSDictionary`.

To process the result strings, use a loop.

```
for (NSString *aString in anArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@ is an %@", aString, NSStringFromClass([aString class]);
}
```